# Inter findByXpath ignore previous selection

Tags: xpath, intern, leadfoot

I'm having issues with `findByXpath` ignore previous selection (selection done with the `findXxxxxXxxx` Commands).

My Page object looks like this

```
class DeleteModalUiComponent {

      constructor(private remote: Remote) { }

      getComponentContainer() {
          return this.remote.findDisplayedByCssSelector('.delete-modal');
      }

      clickModalBotton(text: string) {
          return this.getComponentContainer()
              .findByXpath(`//button//*[contains(text(),'${text}')]`)
              .then(elem => elem.click())
              .waitForDeletedByCssSelector('.delete-modal');
     }
}
```

I would like to base my **Xpath** find according the the container but `findByXpath` ignores the selection of **getComponentContainer()** and selecting from the root.

In the leadfoot the API says the following:

> [`findByXpath`](https://theintern.io/leadfoot/module-leadfoot_Element.html#findByXpath)
>
> Gets the first element inside this element matching the given XPath
>   selector.

But using the `//` prefix in **Xpath** ignores `this element`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `//` prefix in Xpath ignores the current context element because `//` explicitly means 'search from the document root'. To search within the current context element, use `.//`.

Comment: Thanks, using `.//` did the job